# Issue encrypting with DES in PHP

Tags: php, encryption, des

Im trying to encrypt some information about a formulary i created in HTML and managed with a PHP Script, heres the formulary.
[Formulary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwfzO.png)

In php i created this

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Bogota');
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "TallerFB";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Error en la conexión a la base de datos: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$fecha_hora = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$banco_origen = $_POST['banco_origen'];
$cuenta_origen = $_POST['cuenta_origen'];
$tipo_cuenta_origen = $_POST['tipo_cuenta_origen'];
$banco_destino = $_POST['banco_destino'];
$cuenta_destino = $_POST['cuenta_destino'];
$tipo_cuenta_destino = $_POST['tipo_cuenta_destino'];
$numero_identificacion = $_POST['numero_identificacion'];
$valor_transaccion = $_POST['valor_transaccion'];
$cus = $_POST['cus'];
$descripcion = $_POST['descripcion'];

$clave = "BlOcKcH4!n$";

$iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(openssl_cipher_iv_length('des-cbc'));
$cifrado_cbc = openssl_encrypt($fecha_hora . $banco_origen . $cuenta_origen . $tipo_cuenta_origen . $banco_destino . $cuenta_destino . $tipo_cuenta_destino . $numero_identificacion . $valor_transaccion . $cus . $descripcion, 'des-cbc', $clave, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);

$cifrado_ecb = openssl_encrypt($fecha_hora . $banco_origen . $cuenta_origen . $tipo_cuenta_origen . $banco_destino . $cuenta_destino . $tipo_cuenta_destino . $numero_identificacion . $valor_transaccion . $cus . $descripcion, 'des-ecb', $clave, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA);

$iv_cfb = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(openssl_cipher_iv_length('des-cfb'));
$cifrado_cfb = openssl_encrypt($fecha_hora . $banco_origen . $cuenta_origen . $tipo_cuenta_origen . $banco_destino . $cuenta_destino . $tipo_cuenta_destino . $numero_identificacion . $valor_transaccion . $cus . $descripcion, 'des-cfb', $clave, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv_cfb);

$iv_ofb = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(openssl_cipher_iv_length('des-ofb'));
$cifrado_ofb = openssl_encrypt($fecha_hora . $banco_origen . $cuenta_origen . $tipo_cuenta_origen . $banco_destino . $cuenta_destino . $tipo_cuenta_destino . $numero_identificacion . $valor_transaccion . $cus . $descripcion, 'des-ofb', $clave, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv_ofb);

echo "Texto cifrado CBC: " . $cifrado_cbc . "<br>";
echo "Texto cifrado ECB: " . $cifrado_ecb . "<br>";
echo "Texto cifrado CFB: " . $cifrado_cfb . "<br>";
echo "Texto cifrado OFB: " . $cifrado_ofb . "<br><br>";

$clave = "BlOcKcH4!n$";

// Descifrado CBC
$iv_cbc = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(openssl_cipher_iv_length('des-cbc'));
$datos_descifrados_cbc = openssl_decrypt($cifrado_cbc, 'des-cbc', $clave, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv_cbc);

// Descifrado ECB
$datos_descifrados_ecb = openssl_decrypt($cifrado_ecb, 'des-ecb', $clave, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA);

// Descifrado CFB
$iv_cfb = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(openssl_cipher_iv_length('des-cfb'));
$datos_descifrados_cfb = openssl_decrypt($cifrado_cfb, 'des-cfb', $clave, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv_cfb);

// Descifrado OFB
$iv_ofb = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(openssl_cipher_iv_length('des-ofb'));
$datos_descifrados_ofb = openssl_decrypt($cifrado_ofb, 'des-ofb', $clave, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv_ofb);

// Mostrar los datos descifrados
echo "Datos descifrados CBC: " . $datos_descifrados_cbc . "<br>";
echo "Datos descifrados ECB: " . $datos_descifrados_ecb . "<br>";
echo "Datos descifrados CFB: " . $datos_descifrados_cfb . "<br>";
echo "Datos descifrados OFB: " . $datos_descifrados_ofb . "<br><br>";

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "TallerFB";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

$sql = "INSERT INTO transacciones (cifrado_cbc, cifrado_ecb, cifrado_cfb, cifrado_ofb) VALUES ('$cifrado_cbc', '$cifrado_ecb', '$cifrado_cfb', '$cifrado_ofb')";

$sql = "INSERT INTO transacciones (fecha_hora, banco_origen, cuenta_origen, tipo_cuenta_origen, banco_destino, cuenta_destino, tipo_cuenta_destino, numero_identificacion, valor_transaccion, cus, descripcion)
        VALUES ('$fecha_hora', '$banco_origen', '$cuenta_origen', '$tipo_cuenta_origen', '$banco_destino', '$cuenta_destino', '$tipo_cuenta_destino', '$numero_identificacion', '$valor_transaccion', '$cus', '$descripcion')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Transacción registrada correctamente.";
    unset($_POST);
} else {
    echo "Error al registrar la transacción: " . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
<br>
<a href="inicio.php">Click aquí para realizar otra transacción</a>
```

This is supposed to encrypt and decrypt all of the information the user put in the formulary, it does, when i click "Enviar" i put this code to see if this works, apparently it works but with OFB cypher the code is just unreadable, let me show you [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LnJsf.png), it does the encryption process but idk what happen with OFB.

As you can see all of this is being saved in a database, all of the columns in the database appears to be NULL, i was guessing that it could due to the symbols used in the encryption, but once i do

`SELECT * FROM transacciones` it just appears to be empty, not even in PhpMyAdmin im able to see anything from cypher neither decypher.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4WRw.png) the database.

I just eliminated that part of the code where it prints the cypher and decypher in the script theres nothing i can do to get the decypher from the database since it appears as NULL everytime i put anything in the formulary. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9QeqA.png) ima show proof of what does appears with different inputs.

Comment: You must use the same IV for decryption that you used for encryption. It looks like you're generating random IVs for decryption.

Comment: Thanks for your response, im not really sure what to change for the IVs can u tell me please which part am i supposed to change?

Comment: You have to use the **same** iv for both encryption and decryption.